# filtering fields without entering null values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5338ec2a5b5b71242a1c911c"),
"people" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Jhon"
    }, 
    {
        "age" : "30"
    }, 
    {
        "weight" : "80"
    }
]}
```

Query: db.tmp.aggregate({$project:{"people.name":1}})

In the issue:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5338ec2a5b5b71242a1c911c"),
        "people" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Jhon"
            }, 
            {}, 
            {}
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1}
```

How to display only the "name" field blank without {}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) when dealing with arrays in [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

```js
 db.tmp.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$people" },
    { "$match": { "people.name": { "$exists": true } }},
    { "$project":{ "people.name":1 }}
 ])
```

And if you want it as an array then group back:

```js
 db.tmp.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$people" },
    { "$match": { "people.name": { "$exists": true } }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "people": { "$push": { "name": "$people.name" } } 
    }}
 ])
```